# Enforcing parametricity on arguments

Tags: haskell, parametric-polymorphism

Using `RankNTypes` one can enforce various kinds of parametricity. For example, `A id :: A`:

```
newtype A = A { unA :: forall a. a -> a }
```

But how about cases where we *only* care about the parametricity of the function on its argument? For a specific kind of case, the following will work:

```
newtype X b = X { unX :: forall a. a -> (a, b) }
```

For example, `X (\a -> (a, ())) :: X ()`.

I would like to understand how to (or whether one can) construct a parametricity test that works more generally for functions of the form `\a -> (a, f a)`, where `f` may be constant (as above) or potentially parametric itself. This can't be accomplished with `X`. E.g., `X (\a -> (a, id a))` is a type error. Can this be done?

Edit: I'd like to repose or elaborate on the question somewhat. Suppose we have a type of parameterized state transformers:

```
type PState i o a = i -> (a, o)
```

Suppose also that we are interested in statically enforcing that the `a` in an arbitrary `m :: PState i o a` does not depend on `i` in any way. In other words, is it possible to define a function `f` such that `f m` is well typed when `m`'s value doesn't depend on the input (and in that case evaluates to `m`), and is not well typed otherwise?

Comment: The closest you get in Haskell is `newtype X f = X { unX :: forall a. a -> (a, f a) }`. You won't get `X (\a -> (a, id a))` to type check, but you can always use some wrapper isomorphism like in `X (\a -> (a, Identity a)) :: X Identity`.

Comment: Thank you! I realize that. But I'm looking for a static, general way of enforcing this kind of parametricity, without needing to hand-roll a type constructor for every possible way `a` could be used (or not) in the second component. If it isn't possible in Haskell, I'd still be interested in learning why not, or whether other kinds of type systems have an easier time.

Comment: If `f` can be a type-level function, instead of a constructor name, then type inference becomes unfeasible. E.g. consider `newtype X f a = X (f a)` and `t = X True`. What type has `t`? It has several types: `X (\_ -> Bool) Int`, `X (\_ -> Bool) String`, ..., and `X (\a -> a) Bool`. Worse, there is no "most general" type. Result: the user will have to annotate `t` with the wanted type to disambiguate. That's what happens in dependently typed languages (Agda, Coq, ...). Haskell chose to keep type inference feasible (well, in most common cases anyway).

Comment: Yes, you can define `type PState i o a = (a, i -> o)`.  More seriously, I'm still a little confused by your question.  Can you give a few examples of the kinds of things you would have to "hand roll" that you would like to be automatic?  If Haskell was your dream language and did it in exactly the way you would like, what would it look like?

Comment: `PState` supports computations where `a` depends on `i` and ones where it doesn't. I am wondering (non-normatively!) if it is possible to check at compile time whether a given `PState` computation is of one sort or the other (I would like for `PState` itself to support both kinds of computations in principle). Suppose we had such a function `f`. Then `f (\i -> ('a', i))` would be well typed. But, for example, `f (\i -> (i, i))` wouldn't be. (I realize this is somewhat different from the question as originally posed, but for my particular use case, this would be sufficient.)

Comment: As for the sort of thing I don't want to have to deal with manually, I'd want the solution to work for `f (\i -> ('a', ('b', ('c', i))))`, without needing to define a special-purpose parametrized newtype for the output state `(Char, (Char, i))` (cf. @chi's first suggestion).

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to make an explicit type-level function to accomplish this. Normally quantified `Type -> Type` variables are actually assumed to be type constructors (injective functions), which is not sufficient here. But it is possible to have noninjective ones too, they're just called type *families*. The flip side to this is that you need some separate means of actually *indexing* which one you want, because type inference wouldn't work without that.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, KindSignatures, EmptyDataDecls, TypeInType
           , RankNTypes, UnicodeSyntax #-}

import Data.Kind

type family MyTyFun (f :: Type) (a :: Type) :: Type

newtype GState f = GState { unGS :: ∀ a . a -> (a, MyTyFun f a) }

data Af
type instance MyTyFun Af a = ()
type A = GState Af

data Xf b
type instance MyTyFun (Xf b) a = b
type X b = GState (Xf b)

data Wf
type instance MyTyFun Wf a = a
type W = GState Wf
```

```
> unGS (GState (\a -> (a, a)) :: W) 4
(4,4)
```

Comment: In what way does this improve on the solution @chi offered in comments on the OP (asked non-rhetorically!)? In that solution, one needs to hand-roll a constructor for arbitrary cases (and then peel it back off). Here one doesn't need to do the peeling, but all requisite type functions must be pre-rolled by hand. Is the peeling the principal difference?

Comment: Practically speaking, yeah. Perhaps more relevantly, you don't need to _know_ how to un-peel any given value, which would make this more suitable for generic stuff.

Comment: It's very helpful, thanks. Am I correct in understanding that this is principally a problem of type *inference* -- i.e., that the kind of thing I want can be stated in System F, and that the need to pre-roll is solely to get type inference off the ground?

Comment: That's what I think too, but I'm not super expert in type theory.